# can mmv rename files by incrementing an index?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, rename, mmv

Can mmv, a mass move utility, nicely rename files from:

- foo.txt
- bar.txt
- baz.txt

to:

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- 3.txt

The man page is intriguing, but I don't quite follow the directions:

```
   Rename all *.jpeg files in the current directory to *.jpg:

  mmv '*.jpeg' '#1.jpg'
```

Can the `#1` variable be set to an integer which increments?  While I don't doubt that this is possible, is it equally easy (or hard) to just use a bash or other script?

Ignoring the possible problem of overwriting `1.txt` for simplicity.  Or, copy into a subdirectory instead.

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880467/

[Rename files by incrementing a number within the filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40523/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that program on my system —
in fact, I don't specifically recall hearing of it before —
but I read [this copy of the man page](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html),
and it appears that the program does not include
the functionality that you want. 
However, if you especially want to do this with `mmv`,
you might want to try this:

```
mmv -an "*.txt" bogus.target > /tmp/mmv.list
```

The `-n` tells `mmv` not to do any moves,
but just to report what it would have done if you hadn't specified `-n`. 
The `-a` tells it to append all the text files
into the one file `bogus.target` —
in fact, the man page gives a very similar example
(but without the `-n` option) —
I use it here simply to persuade `mmv`
to allow multiple source files to collide into a single target. 
This should produce a `/tmp/mmv.list` file that looks something like

```
bar.txt -> bogus.target
baz.txt -> bogus.target
foo.txt -> bogus.target
```

(I assume that it will list the files
either in lexicographical (alphabetical) order,
or directory order (which may appear to be an arbitrary order). 
If you want some other order,
you will need to find some way to specify that.) 
Then process the file (e.g., with a script, TBD)
to replace the occurrences of `bogus.target`
with `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, etc. 
Then execute

```
mmv < /tmp/mmv.list
```

Caveats: I haven't tried this
(since, as I said, I don't even have the software). 
You should probably do a dry run first on some unimportant files,
and/or backup all your files before doing this.

Note also that this is probably
at least as much work as some of the answers to the questions you linked to. 
As I said, I offer this suggestion
just in case you especially want to do this with `mmv`.

P.S. My answer (above) was partially inspired by [this one](https://superuser.com/a/16040).

Comment: thanks for the research.  I'll take a closer look probably tomorrow.