# Batch renaming files from nonzero start index

Tags: shell-script, rename

I'm merging two datasets, and they're in the format `40000X-????.mrc`. However, they both start with `0000`. Therefore, I want to start the second dataset after the end of the first (if the first dataset has 12 files, then I want the second dataset to start with `40000X-0013.mrc`, and so on).

I found some partial answers online, so my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
c=12
for f in *.mrc ; do
  mv -v "$f" "40000X-$(printf '%0*d' 4 $c).mrc"
  let c=c+1
done
```

**Expected outcome:** Renames all files in order, starting from 12, continuing until it has processed all the files.

**Actual outcome:** Due to `-v` option it actually claims to have renamed all of the files, but on inspection of the directory, only the last 12 seem to remain. From testing, this is dependent on the start index `c`, and if I change it, it can indeed iterate through more, but it messes up the starting index.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: You have to rename them in descending order, see the technique used in [the answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40563)